# How to show/hide only one selected item from list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my article list. I want to make "see more" button but with code i've created when i click "More..." only newest feed reveal. Maybe you have some idea how to make it work?

```
var content = document.getElementById('visibleContent').value + '<span id="more_text">' + document.getElementById('readMoreContent').value + '</span>',


function addArticle() {
  var container = document.getElementById('article-content');
  var html = '<ul>';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += '<li> <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp"> <div id="articleHeader'+i+'" class="mdl-card__title articleHeader"> <h2 id="articleTitle" class="mdl-card__title-text">' + data[i].doc.title + '</h2></div> <div id="articleContent" class="mdl-card__supporting-text item">' + data[i].doc.content + ' </div> <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border"> <button id="read_more" onclick="return showMore()" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--primary"> More... </button> <p id="time">' + data[i].doc.time + '</p><div class="mdl-card__menu"> <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"> <i class="material-icons">share</i> </button> </div> </li>'
  }
  html += '</ul>'

  container.innerHTML = html;
}

function showMore() {
  var text = document.getElementById('more_text');
  if (text.style.display === "block") {
    text.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: That `showMore()` function does something very specific and very straightforward.  It shows/hides the `id="more_text"` element.  Is that not happening for you?  Is that not what you want it to do?  What specifically is the problem here?

Comment: `showMore()` makes text visible after clicking "more..." button. My problem is that when I have 4 feeds, only in the last one i can show more text. Even if i click "more..." button in other feed only newest one reveal, not the one i want.

Comment: Where is your HTML ?

Comment: @Pugazh In Javascript loop.

Comment: you cannot have more than one element with the same `id` value. If all of your elements have the same `id` it will only affect the last element with said `id`. You need to add a number or similar to the end of your `id` value like this example `id="moretext_1"` then when an event is triggered on that element you can specify the id `this.id` when determining which element to control.

Comment: @pokeybit Ok. Now every item has unique `id` But how to show div with `id="more_text_1"` using `this.id` on "More..." button? Because if i write something like that `<button id="showMore" onClick="showMore(this.id)>More...</button>"` It will give me id of the button.

Comment: Sure I'll write an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You cannot have more than one element with the same `id` value. If all
>   of your elements have the same `id` it will only affect the last element
>   with said `id`. You need to add a number or similar to the end of your
>   `id` value like this example `id="moretext_1"` then when an event is
>   triggered on that element you can specify the id this.id when
>   determining which element to control.

This uses the method explained above, there are far neater ways of doing this. Maybe enhance on it yourself.

```js
function showMore(idval) {
  var text = document.getElementById('read_more_'+idval);
  if (text.style.display === "block") {
    text.style.display = "none";
    } else {
    text.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="articleContent">Some content</div>
<button onclick="showMore(this.id);" id="x1">Toggle More...</button>
<div id="read_more_x1" style="display:none;">test 1</div>
<hr>
<div id="articleContent">Some content</div>
<button onclick="showMore(this.id);" id="x2">Toggle More...</button>
<div id="read_more_x2" style="display:none;">test 2</div>
<hr>
<div id="articleContent">Some content</div>
<button onclick="showMore(this.id);" id="x3">Toggle More...</button>
<div id="read_more_x3" style="display:none;">test 3</div>
```

Also in keeping with your post, below is an example for how to loop increment the variable `i`.

```
var text = '<div id="articleContent" class="mdl-card__supporting-text item">Some content </div>
<button onclick="showMore(this.id);" id="x'+i+'" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--primary"> Toggle More... </button>
<div id="read_more_x'+i+'" style="display:none;">test '+i+'</div>'
```